# JSQMessagesviewcontroller can't perform segues

Tags: swift, jsqmessagesviewcontroller

so I created a chat view controller using the JSQMessagesViewController following this tutorial here: https://learnappmaking.com/chat-app-ios-firebase-swift-xcode/#comment-1930 my code is more or less the same, I didn't tweak anything significant in it, the tutorial is only for a single view controller so I added another view controllers for the app but every time it perform segues, I get the error SIGABRT, no matter if I segues with performSegue or with the back button in navigation bar, it keeps giving signal SIGABRT. any help would be appreciated.

this is my viewdidload:

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    senderId = "1111"
    senderDisplayName = "Bob"
    title = "Steve"

    inputToolbar.contentView.leftBarButtonItem = nil
    collectionView.collectionViewLayout.incomingAvatarViewSize = CGSize.zero
    collectionView.collectionViewLayout.outgoingAvatarViewSize = CGSize.zero
    let query = Constants.refs.databaseChats.queryLimited(toLast: 10)

    _ = query.observe(.childAdded, with: { [weak self] snapshot in

        if  let data        = snapshot.value as? [String: String],
            let id          = data["sender_id"],
            let name        = data["name"],
            let text        = data["text"],
            !text.isEmpty
        {
            if let message = JSQMessage(senderId: id, displayName: name, text: text)
            {
                self?.messages.append(message)

                self?.finishReceivingMessage()
            }
        }
    })
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
```

Comment: JSQMessagesViewController is deprecated.

Comment: "I get the error SIGABRT,": Any error message in console that could give importants clues about why it crashes and how to fix it?

Comment: Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
 Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
 Try this: 
  (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
  (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it.
there's this error message in the console.

Answer (score 0):

SIGABRT (signal abort) is typically from a referencing error in your storyboard. Did you ever change the name of a class or make a connection from a button of one view controller to another and then delete it? If you changed the name of a class you must make the sure the name in the code of the class matches that. If you deleted a button connection between view controllers, click on the controller itself and under the connections tab you must delete it.

Comment: yes I thought that was the case at start aswell, but it wasnt so, because I used navigation controller and even if I just press the back button it would give me the sigabrt error